# Stawpoll can't create poll

Tags: python, api

I am working on a program that includes a strawpoll. As far as I can tell this code should work to create a poll however it is returning an error page instead of a poll. Here is the [api](https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API)

```
json = json.dumps({"title": "Question", "options": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]})
poll = requests.post("http://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls", data = json, headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

This is the url it returns

```
https://www.strawpoll.me/error?aspxerrorpath=/api/v2/polls
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, strawpoll.me' api have been broken for quite some time now. You can still retrieve the polls but creating one redirects you to the error landing page.

Answer (score 1):

Try posting your request to http**s**://**www**.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls:

```
data = {"title": "Question", "options": ["option1", "option2", "option3"]}
poll = requests.post("https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls", json=data,
                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

print(poll.url)
# https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls
print(poll.json())
# {'multi': False, 'title': 'Question', 'votes': [0, 0, 0], 'id': 16578754,
#  'captcha': False, 'dupcheck': 'normal', 'options': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']}
```